# node.js & EJS : in the APP.JS app.get doesn't work

Tags: javascript, node.js, get, webstorm, ejs

I use Webstorm. I prepared a form in page6 with the method "get". But the app.get doesn't work. There aren't any errors. it seems APP.JS ignores.

in PAGE6.EJS

```
<form action="/page6" method="get" >
     <input type="email" class="form-control" id="to">
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Send</button>
</form>
```

in the APP.JS

```
app.get("/page6",(res,req)=>{
  console.log("Ok.Done.");
});
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I shortened the code. Deleted the unnecessary lines.

Comment: Sorry. I was adding an explanation to my question. My mistake. That comment was for my question...

Comment: Sorry myself, somehow Stack Overflow showed this comment as a reply to me. If you want to add information to your post, [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51798474/edit) it!

Comment: OK. thank you. There aren't any errors. it seems APP.JS ignores. I don't understand why.

Comment: "it seems APP.JS ignores" — What doesn't happen that you expect to happen? Are you looking for the output of `console.log`? Where?

Comment: I edited my question and add a screenshot. I use webstorm. I am testing if my form action goes well  so I tried console. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the PAGE6.JS

```
 router.get ('/page6",(res,req)=>{
      console.log("Ok.Done.");
 });
```

I think the get method is handled by the JS of router page, not the APP.JS. it may be about webstorm properties.